# Can't center text on css <div> footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add centralized text on a footer, but the text always stays on the left, even after setting the margin to auto, and `text-align: center`. 
Can anyone figure out what's missing?

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  background-color: #393e46;
  height: 15%;
  top: 360%;
  padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hyperlink {
  color: #cdffeb;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<a class="hyperlink" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/diogo-neiss-501001165/">LinkedIn</a>
<a class="hyperlink" href="https://github.com/diogoneiss">Git Hub</a>
</div>
```

Comment: move text-align to the footer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding `text-align: center` to footer fixes it, here is a live sample https://codepen.io/dobladov/pen/WLPoJy

Comment: thanks, I mis used the text allign on the children class. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #393e46;
  height: 15%;
  top: 360%;
  padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hyperlink {
  color: #cdffeb;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<a class="hyperlink" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/diogo-neiss-501001165/">LinkedIn</a>
<a class="hyperlink" href="https://github.com/diogoneiss">Git Hub</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to get text aligned in the center of the footer div. You can  place the text-align on the footer div

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` like this

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #393e46;
  height: 15%;
  top: 360%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hyperlink {
  color: #cdffeb;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using flex, easy and clean to manage. Simply set the `flex-direction` to `column` and align the items in the `flex box` to center.

```css
.footer {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.hyperlink {
  color: tomato;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<a class="hyperlink" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/diogo-neiss-501001165/">LinkedIn</a>
<a class="hyperlink" href="https://github.com/diogoneiss">Git Hub</a>
</div>
```